# is single radio button available in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am trying to drag-drop a single radio button from object library in cocoa. But there is "radio group" object is available to drag-drop. In radio group has two radio button.

Is there any way to create a single radio button in cocoa application or hide the one radio button from radio group?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it one by going to attribute inspector and set the cell count to 1. but you have to handle the behaviour by your self logically.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this screenshot from? I mean what object are you editing?

Comment: its NSMatrix(Radio Group) object

Comment: Jesus how come I've never heard of that in a full year of iOS.

Comment: Because it's for OSX(Cocoa), not available in iOS :)

Comment: Alright that makes sense. I can't believe I've spent that long for an OSX answer just because this dude can't tag properly.

Comment: Fair enough, just, ergh. There was the iOS tag and it went into my feed, it's not like it was obvious :P

Answer (score 1):

Single radio button is not available in object library in cocoa. You can just use a normal UIButton and give its normal and selected images in Interface Builder.

Alternatively, you can just use a custom library for radio button like this one : https://github.com/onegray/RadioButton-ios

Answer (score 1):

You should use a simple UIButton.

You can set different texts/images depending on a button status, like **Devanshi** suggested. The if/else approach is a bad idea though, because cocoa already provides these and are much more simple and small.

There are two ways, either `storyboard` (if you use it) or `programatically`, wherever you create your button (most likely `viewDidLoad`).

**If you are using Storyboard**

Storyboard is pretty straightforward, select your button, and under the "State" you can chose different settings. Each settings will actually load different parameters for the next settings. Like the title and image for example.

- Just go on state "default" and set an unchecked box as image.
- (You can)go on state "Highlighted" and set a temporary highlighted box as image; this is not mandatory.
- Then go on state "Selected" and set a checked box as image.
  [image: Setting 1]   [image: Setting 2]

And you're done.

**If you are using only code**

The programatic way to do this is fairly simple.

I assume we have a button called `btSend`,

`UIControlStateNormal`, `UIControlStateSelected`, `UIControlStateDisabled`, `UIControlStateHighligted`, are the states you can use. I used disabled and normal (enabled) here.

```
[self.btSend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SendIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btSend setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SendIconGrayed.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

With this, you'll be up and running too.

**After setting that up**
Now that your buttons know what to show depending on their state, you need to add a selector method for your action (an `IBAction`), in which you will need to invert the state of your current button. You probably already have that, just add a boolean.

checkBoxSelected is a boolean that I created as an instance variable (on top of .m file). You can set it to "NO" in viewDidLoad if your radio is not selected by default, and to YES if it is selected by default.

```
@implementation TermViewController{

    BOOL checkBoxSelected;
}
```

here is the method that is  called when I press the button

```
- (IBAction)tapRadioButton:(id)sender {
    checkBoxSelected = !checkBoxSelected;
    [_btCheckbox setSelected:checkBoxSelected];
}
```

You probably have "something" that checks if your checkbox is selected, to know that, you can either get the state of your button by using `self.yourButton.state`. This will return a `UIControlState`, just check if it's `Normal` or `Selected` or `Disabled` or `HIghlighted`.

Or you can check the Boolean "checkboxselected" if it's YES or NO :)

If you have many radio buttons, you can save all those boolean values in a dictionary. the key would be your button number for example, and the object would be YES or NO. if you press the button, (like shown before), change the button state and also change it in the dictionary. At the end you have all your states in the dictionary.

I didn't explain all that in my first writing because that wasn't really a part of your question :) I hope this helps.

Comment: Your button needs an action to be set on Selected/Normal after each action (if On, set Off, if off, set on)

Comment: you say without coding you can do it by storyboard.

Comment: There you go, I added more information. It's all explained as clearly as possible, if you need help you can ask !
It works, you just need to set it up properly and make sure you understand what you are doing (otherwise you'll get confused)

Comment: you say me without code you can do it . but now you write code.

Comment: Well, it's programming. You will have to add code at some point. But according to your question, the button states are made without code and will change by  themselves when you tap. But **you still have to code the actions your buttons do**...
In this case : changing the state of the button.

Comment: Only you replace state with if condition nothing else.  But thanx

Comment: ?? What do you mean nothing else? I explained way much more than what you asked in the clearest way I could. I "only" replace state with a bool because thaht's all there is to do. This is stupidly simple

Comment: Sorry, if you fill hurt.

Comment: I'm not hurt I just don't understand how you're not getting this to work just because you have to type 3 lines of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78525/discussion-between-devanshi-and-zil).

Comment: Wait I thought you were the OP, didn't notice you were someone else... >_<.
All this for nothing.

Comment: sorry, by mistake i press 'automatically move this discussion to chat' button.

Answer (score 0):

For radio button can use simple `UIButton` and maintain state of it and replace the image of on click event.

1) Declare globally in view

```
BOOL isChecked;
```

2) On button click event

```
if (isChecked)
    {
        [_btnRadioBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk_uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        [_btnRadioBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk_check.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    isChecked=!isChecked;
```

3) And get the status of it.

```
if (isChecked)
{
// Here write code of radio button when selected
}
else
{
// Here write code of radio button when unselected
}
```

Comment: @Zil if you have small code then upload it i want it, for feature use.

Comment: I was writing down an answer and planned on telling you :) There you go.

it's a 2-liner in code, and zero lines if storyboard are used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**MVRadioButton**](https://github.com/mrugrajsinh/MVRadioButton) to add animated radio button in iOS. This is very simple Drop in and easy to integrate Custom Control.

Its using CoreAnimation and Layers to Give it look and feel exactly like a Traditional Radio button that we have seen on Web.